# How can I dual boot Chromium OS alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, chromeos

I am using Ubuntu 15.10.
I want to dual boot it with Chromium os.
I checked out the official website, but could not clearly understand what each step meant. Hence, I am a little wary of the process.
Please help me.

Comment: Do you need help installing Chromium OS, help with dual booting with Ubuntu in general, or both?

Comment: just installing chromium os

Comment: Unless some part of your question relates to Ubuntu you will probably have better luck elsewhere (Chromium OS forum or mailing list).